# Export function from React functional component and use it elsewhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to export function from one of my functional component that is using hooks to another one. I want to prevent redundant code appearing in my components.

I have tried to create separate `function.js` file where I wanted to place some of my functions but `useDispatch` hook makes it impossible as it throws hell a lot of errors in every attempt to make it work.
I was searching for solution and trying some `export` statements in different combinations.

What I want to do is to export my `toggleDrawer` function from `Layout` component to other components and here's my code. I'm sure it's very easy and I'm missing something.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import Header from '../Header/header'
import DrawerItems from '../DrawerItems/drawerItems'
import { REDUCERS } from '../../Config/config'

import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useDrawerStyles = makeStyles({
    paper: {
        width: '175px',
        padding: '10px'
    }
})

const Layout = props => {
    const { isDrawerOpened } = useSelector(state => {
        return {
            ...state.interface_reducer
        }
    })
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const drawerClasses = useDrawerStyles()

    const toggleDrawer = (side, open) => event => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return null
        }

        dispatch({
            type: REDUCERS.TOGGLE_DRAWER,
            payload: open
        })
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header/>
                <Drawer classes={{paper: drawerClasses.paper}} open={isDrawerOpened} onClose={toggleDrawer('left', false)} >
                    <DrawerItems/>
                </Drawer>
                { props.children }
            </React.Fragment>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: A few options: have `dispatcher` as parameter (and bind the correct arguments in a lambda, you're already doing this then it won't hurt). Define your custom hook (not something I'd do here). Just extract the _common_ logic and share that, event handlers are seldom _shared_ but some of their logic might be. In general: do not overthink the "no duplication" guideline, sometimes it just does not make sense. Also I'd check the `onClose` logic, it is more convoluted than it should be...you're calling a function to return the handler...it might be a lambda for the handler itself

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `onClose` is correct, it's doesn't fire on render, i have checked, it's only a prop passed to `Drawer` component.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function in another file. Or define it in that file and export it. Then you can import it in other files for other components.

Comment: I have tried this but dispatch hook gives errors saying that I have violated hooks rules and it can be only used in functional component.

Comment: Ah ok, and so I have another question: Do you want this function, that you're calling from anywhere, to affect the state of this component? Or to affect the state of the component you're calling it in?

Comment: The easiest solution is, once the function is defined in your functional component as you have it above, define a global function on the `window` object. `window._toggleDrawer_ = toggleDrawer;` And then you can call `window._toggleDrawer_();` from anywhere.

Comment: Yup it's supposed to affect this specific `Drawer` component. To visualize problem it's SideNav menu and I want to close it from some other components.
I have solution for my specific problem because elements that are supposed to close SideNav are this element children and i can pass this function by props to `<DrawerItems toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer}/>`, just like that. 
But i want to share functions between components without passing them with props.

Comment: Considering that you're using redux, surely the solution isn't to have a global function that anything can call, but to just use a Redux action right?

Comment: Well originally I wanted to create separate file with all the functions that are calling Redux. I don't want to pass them and drill with props to pass one function to another component, My idea here is to create something like function store containing all Redux calls from where i can get function that i need and use them anywhere.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, a function store. Literally create a file called functionStore.js which exports an object, and initially just define one function on that object: `addFunc`, which accepts a string (name) and a function (func), and in that function, write `this[name] = func;` Then, in any other file where you import functionStore, you can call `functionStore[name]()` to call that function

Comment: I'll try that, i also have thought about something like `<ReduxFunctionProvider/>` component that will wrap whole app under `<Provider/>` and make all the functions declared inside it avalible to all it's child components.